# c++ programm Permission denied in Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu-14.04

I have installed Qt for Ubuntu but when I try a simple program a window appear and it has
Can't execute 'file path' permission denied 
I had the same problem with Code::Block so I removed it and install Qt but still has the problem
I'm new to Linux

Comment: Short on details so it is hard to tell, BUT there is one possibility. Codeblocks doesn't always handle spaces in a path name properly when creating a project. If your project is in a path that contains a space anywhere in it, I'd try it in a path with no spaces and see what happens.

Comment: have you tried running codeblocks as root?...although i don't think this is the right thing to do

Comment: So I guess one way to find out is ask the question. What is the full path (directory) where you are creating your project?

Comment: The project name is FirstQtproject

Comment: If it was on Ubuntu using Qt(or Codeblocks) and the error was `ptrace: Operation not permitted` then I'd know what was going on. That would be a different issue. 

Exactly what is the error message you are getting? Your question is vague about exactly what the  permission error is. Depending on how it is worded it could be a number of different things.

Comment: the full message
Cannot execute '/media/nasser/Nasser/build-FirstQtproject-Desktop-Debug/FirstQtproject': Permission denied

Comment: Is /media/nasser/Nasser a USB drive or some external device? My best guess is that you don't have proper permission on the /media/nasser/Nasser directory or one of the subdirectories. What happens if you build the project in your home directory - usually in a subdirectory with your account name below /home

Comment: Nasser is a partition(created it when I used windows-dual boot) and it works when I build it in my home directory

Comment: Okay so it is another partition. Probably because it is a Windows partition (NTFS etc) with incorrect permissions on it or the Windows file system doesn't like something about the file and path names. If it works under your `/home` account this isn't a QT or Codeblocks problem. It is more about using Windows partitions in general from a Linux partition which I think warrants a completely different question and probably better posted to Stack Overflow's sister site [SuperUser](http://superuser.com/) . That is assuming you really wish to use some place other than your `/home` directory.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

do you have the right to execute the file? 
Try

```
chmod u+x filename
```

Comment: sorry but where I type this/I write it in the command but doesn't happened and what do mean with filename the program I made or Qt

Comment: @Nasser In the `Terminal`.

Comment: @Nasser Right click on the file, click `Properties`, go to `Permissions` tab and check the `Mark as executable` checkbox.

Comment: the full message
Cannot execute '/media/nasser/Nasser/build-FirstQtproject-Desktop-Debug/FirstQtproject': Permission denied

Comment: Weird, could you please copy the file somewhere else and try to run it?